# Python package installation

Tags: installation, python, package-management

I have been using Python for years, both versions 2.x and 3.x and both are installed on my machine.

But I am still unable to install packages properly, this is still black art for me !

When I attempt to get new modules, even following what is documented, I often face problems with the modules not being found. For instance, I just tried with SymPy and executed the setup script, but still get a "`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sympy'`" message.

Is there a simple reference explaining how Python installations work and what are the involved folders ? What are the magical recipes ? And how to handle multi-version installations ?

My question is not limited to SymPy. I am under Windows, but the answer can be generic.

Comment: Harry - How did you install SymPy exactly? With pip using specific syntax or what? I saw that the site for this package states "*SymPy officially supports Python 2.7, 3.3, 3.4, 3.5, and PyPy*" so I assume you're running one of those specific versions? I also see on the site is states "*SymPy only depends on mpmath*" so you might ensure you have **mpmath** installed too. You also state you have 2.x and 3.x installed so I suppose you didn't install for one version and your defaults launch the other version? Are you using PyCharm, command line from Linux or Windows or what? More detail please.

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT: sorry, I am not asking a solution to this particular problem with SymPy. I am looking for tutorial resources on Python packages installation. [I have tried an auto-installer and pip, to no avail, but again, I don't want the answers to focus on that.]

Comment: Look over https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449494/how-do-i-install-python-packages-on-windows and see if these answers help any

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT: thanks. These answers mostly speak about installation of Python itself and/or just recommend pip. I need minimum understanding of how intallations work, in order to troubleshoot.